# Inline & Block Form Inputs together

Tags: css, forms, input

I'm trying to give my form a layout like the one shown on this image http://reversl.net/demo/ where the firstname and surname inputs are inline but all other inputs are stacked (i.e. on top of each other). I currently have something like this http://reversl.net/form/ using the following markup;

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
<ol>            
  <li>
    <label for=name>Firstname:</label>
    <input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="Jon" required autofocus>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for=name>Surname:</label>
    <input id=surname name=surname type=text placeholder="Doe" required autofocus>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for=message>Message:</label>
    <textarea id=message name=message placeholder="Type your message here..." required></textarea>
  </li>

</ol>
  </form>
</div>
```

Styled as follows;

```
label {
display: block;
line-height: 1.75em;
}

input, textarea {   
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 2em;
padding: .75em .5em;
color: #999;
border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
outline: none;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
}

textarea {
height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem you need help solving?

Comment: @ktash, Got it sorted. Just needed set the selected li to display: inline block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the first two LIs `display: inline-block` and adjust paddings/margins as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I make it

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <ul style="float: left">
            <label for="name">Firstname</label>
            <input id="name" autofocus="" name="name" placeholder="Jon" required="" type="text">
        </ul>
        <ul style="float: left">
            <label for="name">Surname</label>
            <input id="surname" autofocus="" name="surname" placeholder="Doe" required="" type="text">
        </ul>
        <br><br><br><br><br>
        <ul>
            <ul style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px">
                Message</ul>
&nbsp;<textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Type your message here..." required="" style="width: 536px"></textarea>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

and **CSS**

```
label {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.75em;
}
input, textarea {
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding: .75em .5em;
    color: #999;
    border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
    outline: none;
}
input:focus, textarea:focus {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #aaa;
}
textarea {
    height: 100px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0px;
}
```